# Durandal widgets custom folder structure

Tags: javascript, widget, durandal

I have Durandal application with widgets. I implement it as below and everything works perfect.

```
-widgets
    -widget1
    -widget2
    -widget3

app.configurePlugins({
    router: true,
    dialog: true,
    widget: {
        kinds: [
            "widget1",
            "widget2",
            "widget3",
        ]
    }
});
```

Now when number of widgets were increased I want to organize them better with subfolders (like below).

```
-widgets
    -common
        -widget1
        -widget2
        -widget3
    -special
        -widget4
        -widget5
        -widget6
```

According to the Durandal documentation and searching on the internet I really could not get it how to setup configuration for this kind of approach.
Any help (example, explanation) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [mapKind](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api#module/widget/method/mapKind) api method of the widget plugin to use widgets with non-standard pattern.

```
define(['plugins/widget'],

function (widget) {
    //Syntax
    //widget.mapKind(kind, viewId, moduleId);

    widget.mapKind('widget1', '../widgets/common/widget1/view', 
      '../widgets/common/widget1/viewmodel');

    widget.mapKind('widget2', '../widgets/common/widget2/view', 
      '../widgets/common/widget2/viewmodel');
});
```

And you can use loops if have multiple widgets.